# javascript autocomplete paragraph by word

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I found something close to what I want: https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete

================================================================

I'm trying to add suggestions by word for various auto-tagging purposes. For example, if I type @s I would like suggestions to appear for users like Sam, Steven, etc.

I'm building a task manager and I want to be able to input all parameters by typing.

Everything I'm finding seems to work on the entire string.

I think these are the components I need:

1. A way to target only the current word.
2. A way to position the autocomplete choices relative to cursor postition.
3. A way to replace only the current word.

http://imankulov.github.io/asuggest/ is pretty close, but only chooses one replacement value.

A full working example can be seen on http://workflowy.com when you type in a # or an @ symbol:

[image]

Comment: I thought at first that you meant the function was working on the entire string of the INPUT, but now that I am re-reading it, do you mean you need the function to pull individual words from among possible results? In other words, can you post partial code of what you have, and what you are trying to do, even if it doesn't work?

Comment: If I type "project 581 @s" I want the autocomplete to look at just the word I'm typing and pull suggestions from a list I provide. Does that answer your ?

Comment: Actually, looking at the jquery-textcomplete code from the link you posted - that looks like it does the trick. If you look at the sample about half way down the page, it shows how to have the @ trigger look-up words. But in that one, the @ stays as part of the word, like in most social media settings when you are tagging a person.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated my JQuery solution with a bit more substance, based on what I think you are asking, but might need some feedback from you before I am sure this was what you were trying to do:

```
$('#myinput').change(function() {
    var words = this.value.split(" ");
    $(words).each(function(){
        if (this.startsWith("@")) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "searchwords.php?searchstring=" + this,
                success: function(result) {
                    var wordtoinsert = JSON.parse(result);
                    // ...code continues here
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Non-JQuery solution:

```
change.addEventListener("#myinput", function (e) {
    //Your code here
});
```

Actually, before anyone has a chance to slam me, I am re-reading the OP question, and I think this does not answer it. I think we need more clarification on what she needs.

Comment: So what I'm missing in your answer is the auto-complete part. I want to be able to select a word and complete only the current word I'm in the middle of typing.

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to create all of the code for you. I will have more time to look at this tomorrow. Your original post indicated that you found other solutions that operated on the entire string, and I have shown you how to split that string up and grab only the word that starts with the '@' symbol. Have another look, and I will jump back into this tomorrow. In the meantime, if you have any code you have tried or that would put this in context, that would be helpful also.